Many lookups, aggregated dump, collapse query?
Let's say I have an index where my documents are cars.
Each car some of the following attributes: make, model, color, production year, engine type, length, number of seats, etc.
I have a list of models for a given brand.
I want to retrieve the generic information about each model so I only need to pull one document for each model.
Example: the model is a Camry. I want to know it's a sedan, 5 seats, 15 feet long, etc. I don't care about each individual camry's color, year, etc.
Here is what I thought about doing:

Multisearch: To run many lookups but still, it is not scalable
Match all query with a filter on Make and collapse on Model: Not compatible with paginated search and my index is too large
Aggregate on Model, sub-aggregate on the fields I am looking for, filter by Make. Is that too computationally intensive?

Is there another option I didn't think of, or a workaround for the issues I am encountering?

The new ES|QL query language from Elastic could help with that since it has search-time join capability (aka [ENRICH][https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/esql-enrich-data.html]).
Let's say your cars and models indexes look like this:
PUT cars
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "make": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "model": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "color": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT models
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "model": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

We can add a sample document in each index
POST cars/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"make": "toyota", "model": "camry", "color": "red" }

POST models/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"model":"camry", "type": "sedan"}

Then, all you need to do is to create an enrichment policy that will allow you to join on the model field, as follows
PUT /_enrich/policy/models_policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "models",
    "match_field": "model",
    "enrich_fields": ["type"]
  }
}
PUT /_enrich/policy/models_policy/_execute?wait_for_completion=false

When that enrich policy has run (it can take some time if your models index is big, you'll have a backing index on which you can join.
The ES|QL query would then look like this:
POST _query?format=csv
{
  "query": """
  FROM cars
  | WHERE make == "toyota"
  | ENRICH model-policy ON model WITH type
  """
}

And the results you'll get will look like this, i.e. you've been able to join the model's type (sedan) into your result:
color,make,model,type
red,toyota,camry,sedan

